# inner joining dynamic number of tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that accepts an array of tables as the parameter and after inner joining them returns the resulted rows.

```
function myfunc($tables, $join_on) {
 foreach($tables as $table) {
  // build query
 }
}
```

How do I build the query? for example if `$tables = array('table1', 'table2')` and `$join_on = 'field_x'` then it should create the following query:

`SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field_x = table2.field_x`

Comment: I tried to build an array of joins in the loop  and then implode them, but it seems that `implode` is not suitable for this problem

Comment: what a yucky problem.  I hope it is worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
function myfunc($tables, $join_on) {
    $mainTable = $tables[0];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $mainTable";
    for($i = 1; i<count($tables);$i++) {
        $curTable = $tables[$i];
        $joinField = $join_on[$i-1];
        $sql.= " INNER JOIN $curTable ON $curTable.$joinField = $mainTable.$joinField";
    }

    return sql;
}
```

Of course you need to add some error checking to ensure that you have at least one table in `$tables` and always N-1 elements in `$join_on` where N is the number of tables in `$tables`

Answer (score 1):

As Above function works for 2 tables, while i am researching about 3 tables to work.
can anybody just provide me the flow of it.

I am joining 3 or more table using above code but seems not working.Need to understand the flow.